# Maven problems using GAE and DataNucleus

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-2, dependencies, datanucleus, spring-roo

I'm having trouble retrieving 2 artifacts in my **Maven/Java/Google App Engine** project:

1. <strike>com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:jar:1.0.7.final</strike>
2. com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.3.4

There's a [similar question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877949/problem-using-datanucleus-enhancer-in-a-maven-google-app-engine-project), but each answer brings me back to the same error message.

**More detail**

I don't know if it is relevant, but rather than a version number, my original dependency for DataNucleus contained a variable. I am using Eclipse.

```
<groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
```

I did not include my stack trace in Maven for brevity's sake. Please let me know if it would help to post it. Thank you.

### UPDATE

I was able to get the DataNucleus artifact by changing the version from **1.0.7.final** to **1.0.6.final** (check [this repo](http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/com/google/appengine/orm/datanucleus-appengine/)) and rolling back to **AppEngine 1.3.3** (thanks, @Taylor!). However, I still can't find the repo for **appengine-java-sdk:jar:1.3.3**. There are no jar files [hosted at Google Code](http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.3.3.1/).

Does anyone know where to find the **appengine-java-sdk jar**?

Comment: Those artifacts are not from the DataNucleus project. They are Google artifacts, so you need to find a Maven2 repo that has them ...

Comment: I'm very new to this. Where would I configure the project to look elsewhere?

Comment: Maven(2) has a file pom.xml. Look at the repositories section. The Maven documentation should tell you more. I'd guess Google may have some Maven repo, but then maybe they don't (people were complaining about such things some time ago).

Comment: Use version 1.3.3.1 (not 1.3.3) until 1.3.4 is out. The maven-gae-plugin has the most consistent and up to date repo I've seen so far. The only shortcoming is it usually takes them a few days to catch up when there is a new release.

Comment: @Taylor: Where is the jar hosted? I see only poms and zips at http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.3.3.1/

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is here: http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.3.3.1/

Comment: I'm confused because of the naming "appengine-api-1.0-sdk" vs.  "appengine-java-sdk". They appear to be two different things and Maven seeks to look for them in different places. Is the "appengine-java-sdk" really just "appengine-api-1.0-sdk" renamed?

Comment: The appengine-java-sdk is what you would get from running gae:unpack. It's basically the same as the zip you would download from Google. Whereas appengine-api-1.0-sdk is the actual SDK jar in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.3.4 of the App Engine SDK is not yet supported by the maven-gae-plugin. Please see the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/issues/detail?id=61).

Also, based on your latest edit to the question you should NOT be using version 1.3.3. Rather, you should be using version 1.3.3.1 (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/issues/detail?id=57)). Also, the appengine-java-sdk jar is available in the maven-gae-plugin repo (see [here](http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.3.3.1/)).